# Python IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, indentation

I am trying to update a dictionary value in Python. I'm trying to update a value in the dict by subtracting 3 from the value.

```
if buildings == 1:
        workpower -= 3
        if workpower >= 0:
            farmplace1 = int(input("where do you want it?"))
            farmplace2 = int(input("where do you want it?"))
            board[farmplace1][farmplace2] = "F"    
            my_dict['d'] -= 3;
```

I get the following error

```
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level
```

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: Your code should be indented 4 spaces after each if statement

Comment: Edit mode reveals you are mixing tabs and spaces, use only spaces

Answer (score 4):

Change your indentation and ensure it's consistent ( just use spaces or just use tabs, don't mix both ):

```
if buildings == 1:
    workpower -= 3
    if workpower >= 0:
        farmplace1 = int(input("where do you want it?"))
        farmplace2 = int(input("where do you want it?"))
        board[farmplace1][farmplace2] = "F"    
        my_dict['d'] -= 3
```

Comment: it was automated with the tab thing did not know thanks

Comment: there should be 4 spaces ( or a tab ) after each if statement

Answer (score 2):

Check if you use regular whitespaces for all your indents, the most likely you have tab or another space character like that instead of the whitespace.

Mixing space characters may lead to nice visual indents but bad for the interpreter.